# How to share an Internet connection over Bluetooth from the PC to the Phone

Tags: bluetooth

How to share an internet connection from the PC to a Mobile Device (eg: Nokia Phones). I don't have 3G or Wifi enabled on my old nokia phones, only Bluetooth.

Answer (score 3):

I guess this may work for you

> http://blog.larsstrand.org/2009/04/sharing-internet-connection-over.html

---

Comment: Blueman is not working on 11.04, 11.10 or 12.04 for sharing internet connection from the PC to the Phone over Bluetooth. It only connects and works just the same as the default Bluetooth manager.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

While setting up the new device, check the box Use your mobile phone as a network device. After pairing with mobile phone, make sure to activate automatic connection. To do that, go to the bluetooth menu on your phone -> Paired device -> Scroll to the Ubuntu device -> Option -> Select "Yes" for "Auto-connect".

After that, on Ubuntu, click over the network icon on taskbar -> select "Nokia X2-00 Network". Now it is connected. You are done. Open the browser and try to open any page.

Comment: While this answer might be helpful to some, my interpretation of the question is that he would like to share his internet connection the other way around; So share from connected PC to a mobile device without 3G or Wifi via bluetooth.